# Chicago Electoral Precincts before 2011

Tags: data-request

Are there any sources for GIS data about Chicago electoral precincts before 2011. I have FOIAed the Chicago Board of Elections, and they say they don't have any shapefiles from before 2011.

Comment: Did you specify GIS or Shapefiles in the FOIA? I think prior to 2011, I heard they had created all their files in CAD.

Comment: That's what they say, and I have gotten DBF files from them (that are not convertible to GIS). https://www.muckrock.com/foi/chicago-169/shapefiles-for-2007-municipal-general-and-general-elections-40404/

Comment: Yeah, that's the best option. I believe our 2011 files were CAD-based and our GIS converted them. They have since switched to GIS.

Comment: I have seen earlier vintage GIS files floating around though. https://github.com/datamade/chicago-municipal-elections/tree/master/precincts